# Failed to load resource: net:: ERR_CONNECTION_REST

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I need to get large data from database using Ajax web call.
Upto 20000 records the ajax call working fine, But when the record count is more than 20k it showing the error 
"Failed to load resource: net:: ERR_CONNECTION_REST"
in console.

There is no error in DL method.

And here is the ajax call code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceUrl,
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(Data);,
            contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
            dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
            processdata: true,
            success: function (data) {//On Successfull service call
                bSuccess = true;
                //Success code here
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //Error code here
            }
});
```

please help me to clear the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How large is each record?

My first guess would be the size of the request. What kind of server are you using? If it's hosted in IIS you should check the maxAllowedContentLength in web.config.

Comment: Hi Rikard, each record contains 8 columns. Yes we are hosted in IIS And i added maxAllowedContentLength = "1073741824" in web.configfile

Comment: Just to clearify, is it the posting object Data that is large or is it the response from the server?